# Is there a standard notation for the space of linear operators?

Tags: vector-spaces, operator-algebras

I am writing a paper in which I need to refer to the space of linear operators from vector space $\mathcal{V}\rightarrow\mathcal{V}$. Is there a standard way to denote this space, for instance something like $L(\mathcal{V}\rightarrow\mathcal{V})$?

Comment: I've seen $\mathcal{L}(V,V)$.

Comment: Often there is this designation $\operatorname{End}(V)$

Comment: Or $\mathcal{L}(V),L(V)$.  I've also seen $\mathcal{B}(V)=B(V,V)=\dots$ or $BL(V)=BL(V,V)=\dots$ where "B" stands for "bounded", but I don't like them when you also want to consider bilinear maps.

Comment: I think I will avoid End($V$), since if I saw that in print I would have no clue what it was likely to mean. Probably go with $\mathcal{L}(V)$ since it's simplest and reasonably intuitive. Muchas gracias.